# Can someone clarify inheriting private attributes in Python?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, private

[This is in Python 3.6.8] So my impression was that a subclass inheriting from a superclass would be able to access the superclass' attributes freely, even if the attribute was "private". For example:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name
    def __str__(self):
        return f'my name is {self.__name}'
    
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, name, number):
        A.__init__(self, name)
        self.__number = number
    def __str__(self):
        return f'my name is {self.__name}\nmy number is {self.__number}'

def main():
    name = input('name: ')
    number = input('number: ')

    obj = B(name, number)
    print(obj)

main()
```

Apparently, when I try to use `self.__name` in the `__str__` function of the subclass `B`, it throws an AttributeError exception, stating: `AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute '_B__name'`. However, the program works as intended when I use a accessor (getter) method for getting the name instead of `self.__name`. So was my initial impression wrong, or am I making a misunderstanding somewhere?

Comment: Private members are accessible only from the class itself not subclasses

Comment: These attributes are not really "private". They use double-underscore name-mangling . The whole *point* of double-underscore name-mangling is to prevent name collusions in subclasses.

Comment: Also, more philosophically, instance attributes aren't rally *inherited*. And you *can* access that attribute in the subclass, just use `self._A__number`